# How to use an xsl variable in a javascript block

Tags: xslt

I am trying to use an xsl variable in a javascript block in my xslt file and I am at my wit's end.

Here is the XSLT (edited for public consumption):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="a">
         <xsl:variable name="myVar" select="xpath to the node"/>

    <script type='text/javascript'>

            googletag.cmd.push(function() {
        ...
      googletag.pubads().setTargeting('label', '<xsl:value-of select="$myVar"/>');
            googletag.enableServices();
            });

  </script> 

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I transform the XML in Oxygen, this code works fine.  But when I run it through my servlet, which uses  `javax.xml.transform.Transformer.transform(Source xmlSource, Result outputTarget) throws TransformerException`, I get this:
`googletag.pubads().setTargeting('label', ' ');`

Can anyone suggest a possible reason for this discrepancy between Oxygen and my servlet?

Comment: Is your issue that when you run through oXygen the output has a value for the `$myVar` and when run through the servlet there is no value for value-of? It could be a difference between what docs are sent to the transforms. What is the xpath to the node? Are you sure that it is matching? Reduce to a more simple test of just an XSLT that produces the value of the `$myVar` to verify that you are correctly matching when run through the servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead as contents of your variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="myVar" select="'xpath to the node'"/>
```

This ensures the contents is seen as a literal string. Possibly Oxygen is forgiving enough to ignore it and your Java is (correctly) not -- it's an error, because inside the quoted string you should put an *expression*.

The outer double quotes do not take part in forming the expression, only what's inside. That way you can express either the *string* `'1+2'` or the *sum* `1+2` in a variable.

Comment: I still haven't resolved this issue but I believe we may have XSLTs that are clashing.  This is something that can't be simulated in Oxygen.  I will post as soon as I have some hard evidence. Thanks.

Comment: I'm almost too embarrassed to admit how this issue was resolved.  The reason that the XSLT was working in Oxygen is that I was feeding it XML with the node I needed.  It turned out that in production, the XSLT was using different XML, which did not include the node I needed. The simple fix was to add that node to the XML and viola, mystery solved.  Duh!   Thanks to Jongware and Mads Hansen for helping me home in on this blunder.